# How to send email to multiple recipients when new row inserted ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm using SQL Server 2014

I have a table `A` with these columns:

```
planNo, parcelNo, id
```

And another table `B` with these columns:

```
planNo, parcelNo, userEmail
```

When a new row is inserted into table `A`, I want to send an email to `userEmail` for all rows in table `B` that has the same `parcelNo` and `planNo`

Comment: This could be done using an insert trigger that executes sp_send_dbmail (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) in a loop for each recipient. If the recipient list is large, it would be better to send the emails asynchronously from a Service Broker proc activated by a message sent from the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the answer, because you have tagged the question [triggers](/questions/tagged/triggers).

In my opinion, sending emails through triggers is dangerous. I much prefer an API based approach that uses stored procedures. Mistakes in triggers can cause the database to lock.

Instead of inserting a row directly into the table and having a database trigger do the email, call a stored procedure to insert a row in `A` and then send the email in the stored procedure. So, the stored procedure would look something like this:

```
create procedure usp_InsertAndEmail (
    @planNo ??,
    @parcelNo ??,
    @id
) as
begin
    declare @email varchar(255);

    insert into a(planNo, parcelNo, id)
        values (@planNo, @parcelNo, @id);

    declare cursor b_cursor for
        select email
        from table b
        where b.planNo = @planNo and b.parcelNo = @parcelNo;

    open cursor b_cursor;

    fetch next from b_cursor into @email;

    while (@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin
        -- do email send however you do it
        fetch next from b_cursor into @email;
    end;
    close b_cursor;
    deallocate b_cursor;
end;
```

This approach also allows you to check for errors on the emailing.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s . . . You are absolutely correct, of course.  I often prefix stored procedures with `usp_` (so using `sp_` was simply not thinking hard enough).  I do so even though I don't prefix column names or table names or schema names or database names, so I wonder why I use the prefix sometimes.

Comment: First thank you, but does this work even when I import to table using Excel file or any data source ?

Comment: @Zizooj . . . I table in SQL doesn't know where the data comes from, so I don't see what the source of the data has to do with anything in the stored procedure.

Comment: Quick question , in your solution when I add new row with an duplicate id it will not insert it but it will send an email so when ever the insertion operation failed it will send an email anyway, is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use PHP?

```
    $requete= 'SELECT * FROM B WHERE planNo=\'.$plannumber.\' AND parcelNo=\'.$parcelnumber.\'';
$result = $bdd->query($requete);
    if($result)
                {
                    while ($donnees = $result->fetch())
                    {
                        $email=$donnees['userEmail'];
                        $header='From: Name Surname <your_email>'."\r\n";
                        $title='title of your mail';
                        $message='your message';
                        mail($email, $title, $message, $header);
                    }
                }
```